# Unable to open excel (.xlsx) file in pentaho spoon

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I have an excel sheet `(.xlsx format)`. But when I try opening it using "`ExcelInput`", I get

> Unable to opendialog for this step.
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error

error. I have enabled the "`Excel 2007 XLSX (Apache POI)`" in content as well.

Comment: Can you find the JVM start-up options in pentaho / ExcelInput and increase the maximum heap size (`-Xmx`)? If it's large already try switching to a 64-bit JVM if you aren't already so you can go above 2GB.

Comment: I am not able to find the start-up option in pentaho

Comment: i changed it to 65535 . Yet not all data is loading. i get only some 15 rows where as there are nearly 15000 rows!!!

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded error

This error occurs especially when the process is out of Memory. It means that Garbage Collection(GC) has been trying to free the memory but is unable to do so. 
Check [this](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/gc-overhead-limit-exceeded) article for more.

The possible solution is to increase the memory size of the application, Kettle in this case. You can do so by editing the "**kitchen.sh / pan.sh**" or "**kitchen.bat / pan.bat**" file located inside the "`../pentaho/design-tools/data-integration`". Increase the **`JAVAMAXMEM`** number to larger number maybe 1024.

Check the image as below:

[image]

Hoping this might help you in reading the excel file :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Spoon client (i.e. the default application used when running the Pentaho Data Integration - PDI), you can change the parameters in Spoon.bat (if you use windows) or Spoon.sh (if you use unix). The java memory parameters are Xms and Xmx. You would find them in a statement like the following:

```
if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms1024m" "-Xmx2048m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

After changing the value, you should restart spoon.